# How can I generate precisely one warning within a tabularx environment?

Tags: tabularx, expl3, package-writing, latex3, documentclass-writing

I realise this is an unholy mix of `expl3` and LaTeX-2e, but most of my code is like this at the moment, unfortunately.

I want to be warned when I fail to set a particular variable. More specifically, I want to receive a single warning each time an empty variable is typeset.

I also want to typeset the variable within a `tabularx` environment. Unfortunately, this triples the number of warnings due, I think, to the way `tabularx` figures out the width of the columns in the tabular.

What is the most elegant and efficient way to prevent the warning from being written to the console/log three times, rather than once, each time it is triggered within a `tabularx` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,tabularx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l_some_empty_bool
\msg_new:nnn { mod } { oh-dear }
{
  mod  ~:~#1~:~\msg_line_context: ~:~thing~not~set.
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \some_thing:n #1
{
  \bool_set_false:N \l_some_empty_bool
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl
  {
    \bool_set_true:N \l_some_empty_bool
  }
  {
  }
  \bool_if:NTF \l_some_empty_bool
  {% how can I stop this being issued 3 times inside a tabularx?
    \msg_warning:nnn { mod } { oh-dear }
    { \some_thing:n } % command context
    \textbf { ?? }
  }
  {
  }
}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    Date & \some_thing:n { }\\
  \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

(And if anybody knows how to persuade an editor to recognise `expl3` warnings as warnings, please do chime in. But I'm assuming this is Just Life.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tabularx suppresses all kinds of tex warnings during trials in particular it sets

```
\hbadness\@M
```

and then disables anyone setting it back by going

```
\let\hbadness\@tempcnta
```

so you can use

```
\ifx\hbadness\@tempcnta
%      do nothing in trials
 \else
    do something in the final run
\fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is that safer and why is it weirder?

Comment: The second seems to work ... thanks. I'd like to know why safer & weird, though.

Comment: @cfr oh because some other locally nested environments may reasonably have locally set `\hbadness` which would throw the test but they are unlikely to have `\let` the primitive to a random scratch cont register. Ah but the reason I did that was to disable anything resetting hbadness so the first test doesn't work, I'll edit. Sneaky I was, in my youth:-)

Comment: Thanks! This works well. Of course, for ages, I assumed I was inadvertently explicitly triggering 3 warnings. Not thinking about tabularx testing ... :(.