Why does `\DTLdisplaydb` in datatool show duplicate rows when used inside a `tabularx` environment?
I am trying to process and display filtered data from multiple files using the datatool package in LaTeX. My goal is to display rows that meet a specific condition (data starting with "64") in a new database and show it using \DTLdisplaydb.
Here is my minimal working example (MWE):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{filecontents*}{db.txt}
ID,CANLog
DUT01,canlogdut01
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{canlogdut01.txt}
Time (abs),ID (hex),DLC,Data (hex)
200,1F8,8,64 111
250,1F8,8,21 CD4
333,148,8,64 222
400,1F8,8,33 CF4
500,148,8,03 D04
510,1F8,8,64 333
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{myDB}{db.txt}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{myDB}{\ID=ID, \CANLOG=CANLog}
{

    \DTLloaddb{myDBsub}{\CANLOG.txt}

    \DTLnewdb{\CANLOG.PlotData}
    \DTLaddcolumn{\CANLOG.PlotData}{64HEX}


    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c} 
        %% loop
        \DTLforeach{myDBsub}{\TIMEABS=Time (abs), \HEX=Data (hex)}
        {
            \\
            %condition
            \DTLifStartsWith{\HEX}{64}
            {%true
              \HEX
              \DTLnewrow{\CANLOG.PlotData}%
              \ExpandArgs {nne} \DTLnewdbentry{\CANLOG.PlotData}{64HEX}{\HEX}%
            }
            {%false
              none
            }
        }

    \end{tabularx}
    
    \vspace{10pt}
    
    \DTLdisplaydb{\CANLOG.PlotData}
    
    \DTLdeletedb{myDBsub}
    
} 

\end{document}

Problem:
When I run this code, the table generated by \DTLdisplaydb{\CANLOG.PlotData} contains duplicate entries. For example, instead of showing each filtered row once, it outputs some rows twice.
Displayed Output:
64 111
64 222
64 333
64 111
64 222
64 333

Expected Output:
64 111
64 222
64 333

Questions:
Why does this duplication occur?
How can I modify the code to ensure that each matching row appears only once in the output?

Solution (thanks to the comment from Marijn):
The issue lies with the tabularx environment. Switching to the standard tabular environment resolves the problem, and everything works as expected!
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
%\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{filecontents*}{db.txt}
ID,CANLog
DUT01,canlogdut01
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{canlogdut01.txt}
Time (abs),ID (hex),DLC,Data (hex)
200,1F8,8,64 111
250,1F8,8,21 CD4
333,148,8,64 222
400,1F8,8,33 CF4
500,148,8,03 D04
510,1F8,8,64 333
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{myDB}{db.txt}

\begin{document}

\DTLforeach{myDB}{\ID=ID, \CANLOG=CANLog}
{

    \DTLloaddb{myDBsub}{\CANLOG.txt}

    \DTLnewdb{\CANLOG.PlotData}
    \DTLaddcolumn{\CANLOG.PlotData}{64HEX}


    \begin{tabular}{c}  
        %% loop
        \DTLforeach{myDBsub}{\TIMEABS=Time (abs), \HEX=Data (hex)}
        {
            \\
            %condition
            \DTLifStartsWith{\HEX}{64}
            {%true
              \HEX
              \DTLnewrow{\CANLOG.PlotData}%
              \ExpandArgs {nne} \DTLnewdbentry{\CANLOG.PlotData}{64HEX}{\HEX}%
            }
            {%false
              none
            }
        }

    \end{tabular}
    
    \vspace{10pt}
    
    \DTLdisplaydb{\CANLOG.PlotData}
    
    \DTLdeletedb{myDBsub}
    
} 

\end{document}

Displayed Output:
64 111
64 222
64 333


I can't reproduce, I get https://i.sstatic.net/pzY6HEBf.png as only output from the MWE (so without the duplicated lines).

It could be a version issue (for either LaTeX itself or datatool), but maybe in your real document you use tabularx or longtable? There the contents of the tabular gets processed multiple times to adjust the column layout, so the rows (in order, as you show in your question) get added multiple times to the database as well.

Ok Marijn, thanks a lot! Hmmmm ok so I will check later. I am not in front of my PC right now. I am using tabularx. I can tell you so far

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401957/how-to-prevent-tabularx-run-a-macro-in-trial-runs or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309642/how-can-i-generate-precisely-one-warning-within-a-tabularx-environment for workarounds for tabularx.
